# log4j RollingFileAppender - issue with file rename

Tags: log4j

i have webapplication hosted in Websphere App Server. it uses log4j version 1.2.15 for logging and below is my log4j config. the log file is not rotating as soon as it reaches threshold, though log4j debugger says renaming to new file. but the same configuration works fine in another environment.Please note single instance of JVM only running in both of my server environments. So there is no chance for locking the same log file by different JVM is not possible.

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.appender.local=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.local.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.local.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.local.File=${applogs.home}\\web-app.log
log4j.appender.local.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.local.layout.ConversionPattern=%d\t%r\t%p\t%c\t%m%n
log4j.appender.local.Threshold=DEBUG
```

**system.out log**

```
[1/9/20 15:41:42:520 EST] 00000086 SystemOut     O log4j: rolling over count=1048745
[1/9/20 15:41:42:536 EST] 00000086 SystemOut     O log4j: maxBackupIndex=10
[1/9/20 15:41:42:551 EST] 00000086 SystemOut     O log4j: Renaming file <nas_path_of_server>\web-app.log to <nas_path_of_server>\web-app.log.1
[1/9/20 15:41:42:551 EST] 00000086 SystemOut     O log4j: setFile called: <nas_path_of_server>\web-app.log, true
[1/9/20 15:41:42:551 EST] 00000086 SystemOut     O log4j: setFile ended
```

Answer (score 0):

### Resolved

I was able to fix the issue. it turned out that nas_path_of_server did not have modify permission for the application service id which caused this issue.